# Skip empty space between 2 fluidRows in a shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the `shinydashboard` below in which I have almost eliminated the header and add an image at the top of the body. Below it there are two rows of boxes the issue is that there is too much wasted blank space between the image and the `fluidRow()` as you can see in the scrshot.

[image]

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(tableHTML)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(titleWidth = 0,
                 
                  tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                          tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 0px}"),
                          tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 0px;}"),
                          tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 0px; padding-top: 0px !important;}"),
                          tags$style(".navbar {min-height:0px !important}")
                  ) ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    checkboxGroupInput("box", "Select box",
                       c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"),selected = "Red")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      imageOutput("image"), # IMAGE TOO BIG AND BOX CANNOT COMPLETELY CONTAIN IT
      
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,uiOutput("box1")),
      column(4,uiOutput("box2")),
      column(4,uiOutput("box3"))
      
      
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,uiOutput("box4"))
      
    ),
    tags$script("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';")
    
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$box1<-renderUI({
    if("Red" %in% input$box)
      box(
        
        "Red",height = 300,width = 5
      )
  })
  output$box2<-renderUI({
    if("Green" %in% input$box)
      box(
        
        "Green",height = 300,width = 5
      )
  })
  output$box3<-renderUI({
    if("Blue" %in% input$box)
      box(
        
        "Blue",height = 300,width = 5
      )
  })
  output$box4<-renderUI({
    if("Yellow" %in% input$box)
      box(
        
        "Yellow",height = 300,width = 5
      )
  })
  
  output$image <- renderImage({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path(paste0('www/', "connect-shopify-to-google-analytics", '.jpg')))
    list(
      src = filename, 
      height = 150,
      width=1700
    )
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like

```
div(style = "padding: 0px 0px; margin-top:-15em",fluidRow(
          column(4,uiOutput("box1")),
          column(4,uiOutput("box2")),
          column(4,uiOutput("box3"))
```